# Version control for my web server

Tags: linux, svn, web2py

I'm building a Web2Py-based web application and am doing most of my development right on a remote EC2 development server.  I would like to version control the entire system, including all python modules, web pages, and Apache config files.  The files are obviously scattered across my Linux box, but I would like to be able to checkout/commit using a single command.  I'm new to SVN on the command line- Is there a way to do this using a some sort of virtual directory with sym links?

Any thoughts are welcome.  Thanks.

Comment: if you decide on a distributed version control system consider mercurial, which is used to maintain the web2py source code on Google Code

Comment: Thanks Richard- looking at Mercurial vs Git now- Leaning Git but don't like the lack of Windows support...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single developer, [Git](http://git-scm.com/) ( [book](http://progit.org/) ) is better suited for convenience. You can "commit" locally very easily, and push changes to a remote server, which could be your EC2 instance, it just needs an SSH connection to work. But I would probably go with a hosted solution like [GitHub](http://www.github.com) or any other hosting solution that has SSH and the ability to install Git. I use GitHub for my [public projects](http://github.com/fuzzylollipop) and [DreamHost](http://www.dreamhost.com) for my "private" projects.

You would put all your files in one directory structure and then *deploy* them using some automated process. For Python I would suggest something Python standard like [distutils](http://docs.python.org/install/) or even [easy_install](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall). For more complicated environments, you want to consider something like [Chef](http://brainspl.at/articles/2009/01/31/cooking-with-chef-101), which will be extremely important if you start scaling out to more than a single EC2 instance. Even without the multiple server needs something like Chef for repeatable automated deployments is what an efficient developer does.

Just don't get tempted to write a "quick and dirty" shell script to do deployments, they are brittle and very un-maintainable. If you don't like Chef, research alternatives and take the time to learn one. The time spent will be made up for down the line.

Comment: Thanks Fuzzy, Git looks awesome- I hadn't considered it.  So do you see an issue with me making my entire /var/www directory a Git repo?  Also, why do you qualify it as "for a single developer"- Have you had issues with collaboration?

Comment: for a single developer git vs svn, git wins, because it is simpler to setup, use and maintain. I think for a time git still wins, because configuration of svn is more complicated than git.

Answer (score 3):

If you've already started developing, the easy route would be to organize an SVN tree and then sym link the modules and httpd.conf. You could also make use of [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and only check in the virtualenv config.

Answer (score 1):

Like fuzzy lolipop I would highly suggest git as well. Especially because of it's low taint footprint. SVN leaves `.svn` folders in each subfolder of your repo, this can get costly if your automated scripts copy/paste them around.

What i suggest is you have a central git repo and a publish script that checks out a version, then copies the files to their locations.

**Alternatively**

You could segment your repo out a bit and use *symbolic links* to wire up your website, however it's probably poor practice to point your production source into a repo, i'd still leverage the replication script method listed above.

Comment: Thanks Aren- but what do you mean by "poor practice to point your production source into a repo"?  I'm not clear on that.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use git for managing websites and config files.

I'm not sure if I would mix the apache configs and website in the same repo, but if I were to take that approach I'd do it in separate branches and set the remote appropriately.

Depending on what OS you're running, etckeeper is nice and integrates well with debian/apt based systems.

Answer (score 0):

Ever think of ghosting the VM to S3? It's almost like the cloud version of "poor mans version control".

I have done the symlinking and although it is a good solution it is not the easiest to work with at first.