# R's devtools - install from github with "configure" file

Tags: r, github, devtools

I have an R package on github that uses a "configure" script (since some of the C code depends on GSL libraries).  I try installing the package using github_install() function from devtools package and get the error:

```
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘wrightscape’ ...
ERROR: 'configure' exists but is not executable -- see the 'R Installation and Administration Manual'
```

Not sure what to do -- are there such a thing as execute permissions for a file on github?  is this a devtools issue or a configuration issue?  (Installing the package from source works fine for me).  The package is here.  https://github.com/cboettig/wrightscape

Comment: @hadley thanks! [bug report](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/32)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now fixed in the latest version of devtools (0.7).

Answer (score 0):

Git does not manage file permissions directly. It is usually the responsibility of a build or install script to adjust permissions correctly once the bits are delivered from git. There are third party tools that can help with this. See the discussion on SO question [Retaining file permissions with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207728/retaining-file-permissions-with-git).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which was caused by my /tmp dir being mounted noexec, and solved by setting a different TMPDIR, as explained [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Running-R)

```
export TMPDIR=~/tmp
```