# "Writeable by group" exception for php scripts which are under git control

Tags: php, git, apache, suexec

I am working on a website which is implemented using a number of PHP scripts. The entire website is a git repository which is running on a dedicated Apache server. The server will serve a website to the world but will not contain any reseller sub-accounts/reseller accounts.

After examining the error log I see the following:

```
SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/test/public_html/t.php" is writeable by group
```

It seems that the permission `g+w` is preventing PHP scripts from executing and simply throws a "500 Internal Server Error" page back to the web browser. Each time I pull from the git repository the scripts automatically acquire the permission `g+x`.

What should I do?

1. <strike>Disable suEXEC?</strike> This doesn't seem to help.
2. Is there a way to disable this "Writeable by group" requirement? would that even be sufficient?
3. Somehow configure git to NOT add `g+w` permission?
4. Something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retaining file permissions with Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207728/retaining-file-permissions-with-git)

Comment: @LajosVeres That question doesn't help me to resolve this problem. How would I need to configure git to not add the `g+w` permission? What do I do with all of the .php files in the project (i.e. wordpress, plugins, etc).

I feel that this is a good quality question which applies to anybody who is struggling to setup a git workflow on a dedicated server.

Comment: Does setting umask to 022 work?  I am assuming it's a linux system.

Comment: @RussHuguley Thanks, if I do that before calling `git pull` that seems to work perfectly. Perhaps I should create a shell script to ease this process.

Answer (score 10):

When running in CGI/FastCGI mode you should edit /etc/suphp/suphp.conf and change:

```
allow_file_group_writeable=true
allow_directory_group_writeable=true
```

Comment: How does one know if they're running in CGI/FastCGI mode...and what if this error happens when I'm not?