# git status not showing permission changes

Tags: git, github

In a git repository I changed file permissions. If I run the command

```
git status
```

or

```
git status -v
```

I do not see any changes. It only shows

```
On branch xxxxx
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

But I did change permissions on files and folders from `644` to `777`. How can I tell git to show me permission changes?

```
( git version 2.2.1 and filemode = true)
```

Comment: Git _only_ tracks the executable bit of files. It doesn't care/track other file permissions (and doesn't track folders at all).

Comment: @Kamiccolo thank you, I do not want to recover anything I want to see changes happend

Comment: @AD7six thank you for the comment. I don't get it, can you please explain a little further what that means. I changed files from 644 to 777

Answer (score 3):

You can enable filemode and Git will also track file permission changes.

```
git config core.filemode true
```

Comment: that does not help, I will update the question with those informations I forgot

Comment: I see, in that case this answer should cover what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207728/retaining-file-permissions-with-git

Comment: That link does help, thank you @tombeynon! (damm my question is a duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

Some filesystems lose the executable bit when a file that is marked as executable is checked out, or checks out an non-executable file with executable bit on. git-clone[1] or git-init[1] probe the filesystem to see if it handles the executable bit correctly and this variable is automatically set as necessary.

A repository, however, may be on a filesystem that handles the filemode correctly, and this variable is set to true when created, but later may be made accessible from another environment that loses the filemode (e.g. exporting ext4 via CIFS mount, visiting a Cygwin created repository with Git for Windows or Eclipse). In such a case it may be necessary to set this variable to false. See git-update-index[1].

The default is true (when core.filemode is not specified in the config file).

git update-index --chmod=+x

This might solve your problem. This Modifies the index or directory cache and Set the execute permissions on the updated files.