# Git status: show mode (permission) changes

Tags: git

When I run `git status`, many files are modified:

```
$ git status
On branch feature-branch
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature-branch'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   file1.txt
    modified:   file2.txt
    modified:   file3.txt
    ...
```

Is there a way to show that these files only changed their permissions (mode), not contents? I imagine the output would be something like this:

```
$ git status
On branch feature-branch
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature-branch'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   file1.txt (100644 → 100755)
    modified:   file2.txt (100644 → 100755)
    modified:   file3.txt (100644 → 100755)
    ...
```

I am aware of `git diff` that will show something like this:

```
diff --git file1.txt
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

but I'd prefer if `git status` was showing me this already.

---

Note: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922806/git-status-not-showing-permission-changes) seems similar but in that case, `git status` was not detecting mode changes at all. In my case, files are marked as modified but I'd like to distinguish plain file edits (modifying content) from just changing permissions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git status not showing permission changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922806/git-status-not-showing-permission-changes)

Comment: It's not, I've added a note to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe git does that. Git keeps these states for the file changes

> ```
>   •   ' ' = unmodified
>   •   M = modified
>   •   A = added
>   •   D = deleted
>   •   R = renamed
>   •   C = copied
>   •   U = updated but unmerged
> ```

Git is smart enough to tell us about renamings, but it keeps quite in the status about mode changes.

But you can make yourself a script that parses the diff of a file and see if the mode has changed, then it changes the output of the default `git status`.