# .npmrc file permission are not stored by git

Tags: git, npm

In my project I want to use a `.npmrc` file to point to a private repository. From the documentation for npmrc we read:

> **NOTE:** Because local (per-project or per-user) `.npmrc` files can contain sensitive credentials, they must be readable and writable only by your user account (i.e. must have a mode of **0600**), *otherwise they will be ignored by npm*!

unfortunately git is not honouring the file permission 0600.

So: how to store the `.npmrc` file in git?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207728/retaining-file-permissions-with-git) may help you out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you found out you are right.

Git doesn't care about file permissions.

> Git only stores two permissions (`755` & `644`), so your need of `600` is not "recognized" by git.

To override it im using a manual script from [this site](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/105133%7C%7CPATCH) or [this](https://gist.github.com/andris9/1978266)

---

#### ***`umask`***

Umask is a process attribute containing permission bits that are removed from newly created files.

Git creates directories and executable files with mode 777, and non-executable files with 666, and your umask turns off some of those bits.

> If you want default permissions to be 644 and 755, you set your umask to 022:

```
umask 022
```

Answer (score 2):

As of now `npm` in version `3.3.12` does not behave like the documentation suggests. It picks up the `.npmrc` file even though the permission is "only" `644`.

Comment: Also at version 3.9.5, even with permissions at 777