# How to give permission from git?

Tags: git, permissions

I want to give permission to a folder, is it possible to give permission from git. If yes please guide me how can give permission to file ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please elaborate your question. What do you mean by give permission? Give who what kind of permissions?

Comment: @Arpan,  I want to give permission as 777 to a folder, in server and I have only git repo access.

Comment: What do you mean you have git repo access? Git cannot be used to change permissions of files, it is not meant for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207728/retaining-file-permissions-with-git