# Not able to commit/push file permission changes to git

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have some files in GIT which have -rwxr-xr-x permissions.

I need to change it to 640 (rw-,r--,---)

I run chmod 640

But when I run git diff or git commit, these file permission changes are not shown or committed.

How can I perform the above? Please help.

Comment: Git will not impose those kinds of restrictive permissions.  It only sets or clears the `x` bit.  The remaining bits are set or cleared according to your `umask` setting on Unix-like systems.  Removing or adding the `x` bit will normally show up in `git status` though, unless you set `core.fileMode` to `false`.  Windows-based systems behave poorly here, but I avoid Windows and am not sure how to deal with that.

Comment: @torek great stuff. You should place that in an answer.

Comment: Git cares only 644 and 755.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21691202/1256452

Comment: @RogérioPeixoto: I'm sure this is a duplicate, I just have not yet found "of what".

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3208143/1256452