# Why git change my file permission when I pull to 660

Tags: git, permissions

When I push a local file that has permission 775 and pull it on my server, it happens that the permissions of the distant file have changed.
It has 660 permissions. I would like all my files to have default permission 755 after the `git pull` but it is not the case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retaining file permissions with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207728/retaining-file-permissions-with-git)