# After git clone files in bin folder become not executable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, macos, permissions, git-clone

I'v got Rails' app git repository with some executable files in *bin* directory. With permissions *646* *-rwxr-xr-x* each. I double checked and permissions are set correctly in git repository, but when I clone the repo I lose "x" for those files, so eventually they are *-rw-r--r--*. Any explanation ?
My system is OSX, but I had many similar repos and it never happened before.

Comment: There is a way to save the permissions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207728/retaining-file-permissions-with-git

Comment: `646` (assuming octal) would be `rw-r--rw-`. Git's commit will always show either mode `100755` (executable) or `100644` (not-executable); extracting such a commit calls `creat` (or `open(O_CREAT)`) with mode 0777 or 0666 respectively, relying on your umask to clear any unwanted bits.

Comment: Thank, changing it to a+x was enough :)